# I want to loop through an object and update the document textcontent when I click on a button

Tags: javascript

https://codepen.io/tochi93/pen/BaBGxLM
am just trying to go through the array of objects and update my `textContent` when I click on the elements but the elements update only the first time that it is clicked. how do I get it to change whenever I click?

```
let newQuotes = document.getElementById("new-quote");
let author = document.getElementById("author");
let text = document.getElementById("text");
let quotes = [
  {quote: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. ", author:"Lorem"}, 

  {quote: "Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,",
  author: "Ipsum"},
]



newQuotes.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
quotes.forEach((items)=>{
  author.textContent = items.author;
  text.textContent = items.quote
})


}
);
```

Comment: Think about what happens in that `forEach`. It loops through whole array and sets text every iteration. So you will always see only the values of the last `quotes` object. You want some sort of variable to keep track of current index and when clicked figure out next index to display without going through the whole loop

Comment: Every click runs the same function to update all the quotes object, thus the same result every click.

Answer (score 0):

As already noted in comments, you should use a `counter` that increments on each click. You can than use that counter to extract the desired Array index.

```js
const totQuotes = quotes.length; // Get total quotes
let currentQuote = ~~(Math.random() * totQuotes); // Random first quote
```

and to **increment and loop** indefinitely your counter **on click**

```js
currentQuote = ++currentQuote % totQuotes;
```

than it's all about using that counter i.e: `console.log(quotes[currentQuote])`

Here's an example that uses a small templating function `template_quote`:

```js
const quotes = [{
    quote: "Is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. ",
    author: "Lorem Ipsum"
  },
  {
    quote: "Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,",
    author: "Ipsum Dolor"
  },
  {
    quote: "Industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,",
    author: "Dolor Sit"
  }
];

const totQuotes = quotes.length; // Get total quotes
let currentQuote = ~~(Math.random() * totQuotes); // Random first quote
const newQuotes = document.getElementById("new-quote");
const quote = document.getElementById("quote");

const template_quote = item => `
  <figure class="quote">
    <blockquote>${item.quote}</blockquote>
    <figcaption>&mdash; ${item.author}</figcaption>
  </figure>
`;

const output_quote = () => {
  currentQuote = ++currentQuote % totQuotes;
  console.clear(); console.log(currentQuote)
  quote.innerHTML = template_quote(quotes[currentQuote]);
}

newQuotes.addEventListener("click", output_quote);
output_quote(); // Init!
```

```css
* {margin:0;}

.quote figcaption{
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div id="quote"></div>
<button id="new-quote">NEW QUOTE</button>
```